# Haskell function head of string as input of a function

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, head

I'm creating an Enigma Machine in Haskell and I have trouble with the following code:

```
encrypt :: String -> [String] -> String
encrypt t [d1, d2, d3]
  | length t > 1 = encryptOne head t [d1, d2, d3] ++ encrypt (tail t) [d1, d2, rotateF d3]
  | length t == 1 = encryptOne head t [d1, d2, d3]
  | otherwise = ""
```

The encrypt-function takes a String, and recursively solves for each Char using the `encryptOne` function. Each iteration, the rotors are turned using a `rotateF` function (early stage, still working this out). The `encryptOne` function looks like this:

```
encryptOne :: Char -> [String] -> Char
```

The problem is the `encryptOne` head `t [d1, d2, d3]` section, where head `t` can't be solved, and the following error occurres

```
    length t == 1 = encryptOne head t [d1, d2, d3]
                               ^^^^
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: [String]
        Actual type: String
```

Does anyone know how to refactor this section, so that head `t` returns the Char to use in `encryptOne`?

Comment: You need to use proper brackets here, so `encryptOne (head t) [d1, d2, d3]`.

Comment: That did solve it partially. I also found the solution, because I was returning a Char, while the encrypt should return a String

Comment: So `encryptOne` returns `Char` type but you try to concatenate like `encryptOne (head t) [d1, d2, d3] ++ ...`. You should use cons `(:)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willem I found the first problem, using parenthesis.

The second problem was a type-problem regarding `encryptOne` . I added it to the question now, and it shows that it is returning a Char, while the encrypt function returns a String. I had to transform the result of `encryptOne` from Char to String to solve it:

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]
```